# How to get the attribute class list

Tags: apex, reflection

Does exist on apex something like [Class.getDeclaredFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29)?

I need to loop on class attributes dynamically :

```
public class MyClass
{
public type1 att1;
public type2 att2;
...
public void function()
{
    for(var in MyClass.Attributes)
    {
       system.debug(var.class);
    }
}

}


....
//then 

MyClass m = new MyClass();

for(String key: MyClass.Attributes)
    m.getValue(key);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can achieve this using JSON.serialize and JSON.deserialize, as described in my answer to this question: [Can I tell which fields are present in an SObject variable?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15741/can-i-tell-which-fields-are-present-in-an-sobject-variable/15758#15758)

Suppose you have a class `MyClass`, with two attributes `att1` and `att2`. We then add a method `getAttributes()` to return a `Set<String>` containing the names of the attributes on that object:

```
public class MyClass
{
public String att1;
public Decimal att2;

public Set<String> getAttributes()
{
    // Serialize our Object into JSON
    String s = JSON.serialize(this);

    // Deserialize it back into a key/value map
    Map<String,Object> obj = 
        (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(s);

    // Return a Set of those fields present on our object
    return obj.keyset().clone();
}

}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
Set<String> attrs = c.getAttributes();
system.debug(attrs);
// ==> {'att1','att2'}
```

To dynamically walk through the attribute values, I would probably leverage [`System.JSONParser`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_jsonparser.htm), which would let you walk through the attributes in an object/class, and provide you with both the ability to obtain the value of the attribute, and its type:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.att1 = 'foobar';
c.att2 = 100.1;
String jsonContent = JSON.serialize(c);

// ==> '{"att1":"foobar","att2",100.1}';

JSONParser parser = 
   JSON.createParser(jsonContent);
// Advance to the start object marker.
parser.nextToken();
// Advance to the next value.
JSONToken t = parser.nextValue();

// Get the JSON type of the current value / token, 
// which is an ENUM of valid JSON types
    // (see http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_jsonparser.htm)

if (t == JSONToken.VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT){
    system.debug('got a floating point number!');
    Decimal decimalValue = parser.getDecimalValue();
} else if (t == JSONToken.VALUE_STRING){
    // Here, to determine advanced Apex object types,
    // you may have to apply some Regex or try/catch conversion
    //
    String stringValue = parser.getText();
    if (stringValue.split('-').size()==3){
        // We have a Salesforce Date value
        Date dateValue = parser.getDateValue();
    } else {
       // and so on for other Apex primitives
       // that are stored in JSON as Strings.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

no as of now, but vote for the idea 'Apex Reflection'

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrVaAAK

Comment: Seb, see my answer, this is indeed possible at present.

Comment: @zachelrath I agree, but you dont get the type of the attribute hence you'd have to test it potentially for each type. As an alternative you'd have to implement a method that returns a map that links the attribute name to its type

Comment: @Seb__Wagner Good point --- I have updated my answer to explain how you can use `JSONParser` to walk through the object.